# How fast can a Green Lantern fly?

Tags: dc, comics, green-lantern, green-lantern-2011

In *Green Lantern* (2011) movie, when the ring first took Hal Jordan to Oa, he crossed galaxies within seconds. He was clearly going FTL. But, he wasn't infinitely fast either (it wasn't like teleport and astronauts were able to see him).

What's the maximum speed of a Green Lantern's flight? Is it also dependent on the will and imagination (not applicable on the given example)?

Comment: Related: [Is Green Lantern faster than Flash or Superman?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/107969/70236) See Thaddeus' answer.

Comment: The correct answer is "At the speed of (green) light"

Answer (score 2):

A Green Lantern can go lightspeed, even FTL, but as a rule will use space warps for fast travel  across a sector, of from one to another.

In the Larry Niven story Ganthet's Tale, Hal Jordan flew near the speed of light, to "red-shift" his power ring's beam, shifting it to yellow.

Comment: Got some links or quotes to back this up?